# Fluentd and FluentBit

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am sending Data for the Fluentd, from the Fluentd.
How can I compress the Data that comes out of the Fluentd? and how could I decompress this data when it arrives to other Fluentd?

Many thanks!

It is like that?

```
<match mydata.*>
  @type any_output_plugin
  <buffer>
  @type memory
  compress gzip
  chunk_limit_size 16m  # 16MB compressed events
  chunk_total_size 512m # 512MB compressed events in total
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [compress gzip option on forward plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/forward#how-to-enable-gzip-compression) do the trick.

```
<match mydata.*>
  @type forward
  compress gzip
  <server>
    host 192.168.1.2
    port 24224
  </server>
</match>
```

Enable this on the sending server, and (from the doc)

> you do not need any configuration in the receiving server. Data
> compression is auto-detected and handled transparently by the
> destination node.

Comment: Thank you so much, Gianluca Pinto!

Comment: you're welcome! If you like my answer (and this solution works) please accept it, thank you